# How to create custom event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I want to make my own Javascript event. Is there any possibility to create my own event just like as click, hover. I want a event that will really work. Like creating a event that will fire when user clicks on cancel/delete button.

Comment: Please, do some research on your own before asking questions on Stack Overflow. Take a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent and https://davidwalsh.name/customevent

```js
var myElement = document.querySelector('p');

myElement.addEventListener("userLogin", function(e) {
  console.info("Event is: ", e);
  console.info("Custom data is: ", e.detail);
});

var myEvent = new CustomEvent("userLogin", {
  detail: {
    username: "davidwalsh"
  }
});

// Trigger it!
myElement.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

```html
<p>Custom Event Element</p>
```

Comment: This is answer is really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Creating an event listener in JavaScript requires doing two things: (1) selecting an element to "bind" an listener to and (2) adding an event listener:

```
// add event listener to table
var el = document.getElementById("#myElement");
el.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert('element clicked!');
});
```

This particular implementation will run the function when the element with the ID `myElement` is clicked.

Check out MDNs page on [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for more information.

---

As the question was regarding "custom" events, you can create custom JavaScript events in the following way.

```
var event = new Event('build');

// Listen for the event.
var el = document.getElementById("#myElement");
el.addEventListener('build', function (e) { ... }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
el.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can read more about custom JS events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Comment: The question is about to creating custom events, not using the default events.